# Cannot add a row to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: c#, google-sheets

I am able to open the worksheet and read cells from the header. The first line in a Google Spreadsheet is the header and I have manually added "Name", "my-val1", "my-val2", "my-val3", "Other" in the Google spreadsheet.

Here is the relevant Google documentation:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/spreadsheets/#adding_a_list_row

I am trying to add a row to the worksheet, but get the rather generic error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." Any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
AtomLink listFeedLink = worksheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.ListRel, null);
ListQuery listQuery = new ListQuery(listFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
ListFeed listFeed = myService.Query(listQuery);

ListEntry row = new ListEntry();

row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "Name", Value = "Joe" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "my-val1", Value = "Smith" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "my-val2", Value = "26" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "my-val3", Value = "176" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "Other", Value = "176" });

myService.Insert(listFeed, row);
```

Here is the error message:

```
Google.GData.Client.GDataRequestException: Execution of request failed: https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/tlb-JYE8eZbWTRPCoqugCqw/od6/private/full ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataRequest.Execute()
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute(Int32 retryCounter)
   at Google.GData.Client.GDataGAuthRequest.Execute()
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.EntrySend(Uri feedUri, AtomBase baseEntry, GDataRequestType type, AsyncSendData data)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert(Uri feedUri, AtomEntry newEntry, AsyncSendData data)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert[TEntry](Uri feedUri, TEntry entry)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Google.GData.Client.IService.Insert(AtomFeed feed, AtomEntry entry)
   at Google.GData.Client.Service.Insert[TEntry](AtomFeed feed, TEntry entry)
   at DesktopControl.GoogleSpreadsheet.addRow() in C:\Users\mark\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\DSCON\DSCON\GoogleSpreadsheet.cs:line 248}
```

Comment: I get **System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, according to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7455239/error-inserting-row-in-google-spreadsheet-using-zend-gdata), the column names must be stated in small letters and without spaces in the code. The row was inserted after changing the code:

```
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "name", Value = "Joe" }); // "Name" changed to "name"
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "my-val1", Value = "Smith" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "my-val2", Value = "26" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "my-val3", Value = "176" });
row.Elements.Add(new ListEntry.Custom() { LocalName = "other", Value = "176" }); // "Other" changed to "other"
```