# 403 Forbidden error for Google.APIs GET

Tags: http-status-code-403

I've been trying to work this out for over an hour and I'm completely stumped.
I'm trying to get Google profile details (such as displayName, gender, etc) from Google APIs.

I'm doing an Http GET like this
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?fields=birthday,displayName,gender,image,url&key={my_api_key}&access_token={my_access_token}

but I keep getting 403 Forbidden errors. Why?
According to Google's documentation here - https://developers.google.com/+/api/ - this is how I am meant to do it.
Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?
(Happy to give more details but not sure what else to offer!)

Comment: Can you put your solution ? maybe try http://stackoverflow.com/a/11414904/4051367

Comment: There's a limit of images you can download without using a personal key.